# how get comments only on post of current logged in user?

Tags: comments

I need a query that get all comments from only the posts where the currently logged in user is the author.

Each user (author) can post a new post. Then I need to show a list of their own posts ( that already works). Now I want a list of all comments (on the currently logged in users posts). So the author has a quick overview of all comments on their posts.

Comment: Please care about your tags. `logging` is neither about `logged in` content or related in any other way to your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the @shanebp ideas of using `get_comments`:

```
$args = array(
    'post_author' => get_current_user_id(), // It will use the current logged in use to grab the comments
);
$comments = get_comments( $args );

// Referer to http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments
$list_args = array(
    'reverse_top_level' => false // Show the latest comments at the top of the list
);
wp_list_comments( $list_args, $comments );
```

This will display the list of comments done on posts from one user.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the `WP_Comment_Query` class supports pretty much everything you want. You might want to use either `post_author` to fetch the comments **or** `user_id`. Both do pretty much the same thing. As you can see, the `post_status` is `publish` and only for the post type `post`. Alter the arguments as you need them.

```
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() )
    return print 'Nothing to see here';

$comment_query = new WP_Comment_Query;
$comments = $comment_query->query( array (
    'status'         => 'approve',
    'type'           => 'comment',
    // 'post_author'    => get_current_user_id(),
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'user_id'        => get_current_user_id(),
    'number'         => 20,
    'offset'         => 0,
    'order'          => 'DESC',
    'orderby'        => 'comment_date',
    'count'          => true,
) );
foreach ( $comments as $comment )
    var_dump( $comment );
```